# Access response payload/data from within a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, httpwebresponse

I am working on a project where it is required to track requests "ajax ones" from certain site, access response payload for some of those requests and act upon them.

So far i managed to track requests and access their headers using the [webRequest api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html), the only problem is that i can't find anyway to access the actual data within those responses.

Is it even possible?.

Please feel free to post any ideas or references that could help.

Thanks and have a nice day.

---

**EDIT:**

An example of what iam looking for is the response tab in the network panel which is part of  chrome's developer tools.

Answer (score 13):

**Network Panel** is a HTML representation of **HAR**(*HTTP Archive format*) **Log**. You can trace each element of the network panel using `devtools.network API`.

You can refer to following code where *TCP Connection time* is being traced as a reference to get started using `devtools.network API` and `HAR Log`.

#### manifest.json

Registered `devtools.html` for tracing network panel events

```
{
    "name": "Network Demo",
    "description": "This is a sample for API's available for Network",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "2"
}
```

#### devtools.html

Registered `devtools.js` to comply with CSP.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="devtools.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

#### devtool.js

req in the following code returns [HAR Log](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec) and you can use it for reading content you need; I have used the HAR for [TCP Connection time](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/#timings) here

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function(req) {
    // Displayed sample TCP connection time here
   console.log(req.timings.connect);
});
```

## References

- [devtools.network API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.network.html)
- [HAR Log](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/)
- [Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)
- [Content Security Policy(CSP)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

Comment: is "devtools.js" but not "devtool.js".can't Edit

Answer (score 2):

The devtools.network API only works if the Developer Tools window is open. For everyday browsing there is no way to access response data. There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058) open which discusses reading/editing the response body.