# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'network')

Tags: javascript, json, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm currecntly working on a chrome extension and I need to access requests in network tab. Found the API called devtools.network. Tried to use it, but It threw an error like this:

```
content.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'network')
    at content.js:1
```

**content.js:**

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function(request){
    console.log(request)
})
```

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "name": "Managebac Grade Calculator",
  "version": "1.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://opengate.managebac.com/student/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery.js",
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "permissions":[
    "network"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "pfp.jpg",
    "48": "pfp.jpg",
    "128": "pfp.jpg"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "pfp.jpg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: hi, check this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147217/9641914, might be this